# Gutenberg Update Fail

Tags: wordpress, updating, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using Gutenberg but i got an update and I gave the update. after that I am unable to save/edit my post/page 
You can see screenshot below
[image]

right now what can I do??

Comment: Clear browser cache.

Comment: I just waste my 3 hours for a simple bloody cache thanks friends
it's working